# SQL Query to show number of stories created in last 24 hours?

Tags: php, sql, drupal, timestamp

I'm trying to create a custom query that will show the number of stories that have been posted in the last 24 hours on a Drupal 6 site.

Stories are stored in the "node" table.  each record has a "created" row that records the UNIX timestamp when the story was posted.

Here's the query I'm trying so far:

```
$sq = 'SELECT COUNT(*) cnt '
    . 'FROM {node} c WHERE created >= dateadd(hour,-24,getdate())';
```

This doesn't appear to be working though.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the overall code I'm trying to use right now:

```
$sq = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM {NODE} n WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)';
```

$q = db_query($sq);

while ($o = db_fetch_object($q)) {

```
            print_r($o);
```

}

That print_r isn't returning anything.  Where's my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing this in PHP, you can just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`. My guess is that it will be faster than doing date manipulations with SQL:

```
$count = db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {node}
          WHERE created >= %d;", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 86400));
```

Alternative you could use `time` to get the current timestamp, but that will be a tiny bit slower than using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` variable.

Answer (score 4):

For MySQL, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM NODE n
 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Mind that `NOW()` includes the time when the statement is run.  If you want to count records, starting from midnight of the previous day, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM NODE n
 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Reference:

- [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)
- [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: Alternatively, wrap the `date_sub(...)` in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: Hmm, I'm goofing this up: <br/>$sq = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM {NODE} n WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)';                                                                                   
    
$q = db_query($sq);
$stats = array();


while ($o = db_fetch_object($q)) {
  $stats[$o->day] = array($o->day, $o->cnt);
                print_r($o);
  
  
}

Comment: @bflora: Why the curly brackets on the table name?  You might need to enclose it in backticks -- `{node}`

Comment: Just posted an edit to the question with the overall code I'm trying to use to test this out.  The print_r statement isn't returning anything....

Comment: @bflora: Thx for the question update, sorry but I have to turn in but I don't know Drupal API, just SQL :/

Comment: But `FROM_UNIXTIME` kills all the performance :-S Why don't just wrap the right operand with another `TIMESTAMP()`? Also - `NOW() - 86400` can be enough precise here ;-)

Comment: Like this? $sq = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM NODE n WHERE (n.created) >= (NOW() - 86400)';

Comment: +1 This is a good answer using only SQL, but not the best to use with Drupal though. On a side note, curly brackets are used to make it possible to use table prefixes without putting them into the written SQL. That's part of Drupal's query wrapper function.